# Which windows registry hives should be checked to verify correct installation of a program?

Tags: windows, registry

As part of an installation test (on Windows 10) I would like to verify that the Windows Registry contains all the keys that I am expecting to be there after the installation (correct keys added / removed). When comparing the entire registry before and after the installation I get quite a few value mismatches (due to changing values) and it also takes some time to check everything.

Hence, my question is if there are any parts of the registry that I could skip entirely during the verification (e.g. because only windows itself can change things there) in order to gain performance? Furthermore, I want to exclude all the parts that store values that are constantly changing. During my investigation I found that there are volatile hives which do not survive a reboot that I need to exclude. Is there anything else that can be ignored?

Comment: Can you clarify what specifically you want to do? You want to verify the *entire* registry? against what & for what reason?

Comment: "I would like to verify that the Windows Registry contains all the keys that I am expecting to be there after the installation." So do that. Verify the keys that you are expecting to change. Ignore all others. There's always stuff going on in the system. It's like saying "I'm testing a tool that remembers where I parked my car. I take a snapshot of the parking lot before and after I park my car, and I see that a lot of other cars change position, not just my car. How do I know which cars to ignore?" Answer: Ignore all of them except yours. They aren't part of your test.

Comment: I want to make sure the installation added/removed only correct keys in the registry. I therefore take a snapshot of the registry before and after the installation and compare those while taking the added/removed keys into consideration. The idea behind checking every registry entry was that I could make sure nothing incorrect was added additionally. If I just have a look at the entries I am expecting to change I will not notice the unexpected changes.

Comment: In that case, you can't ignore *anything*. The installer may have unexpectedly modified one of your ignored keys. You'll have to study each modification and decide whether it is something your installer changed accidentally. This is like comparing the two photos of the parking lot to decide if your car damaged any other cars. Any damage you see between the two photos might be due to your car, or maybe not, you can't be sure.